# Is the li-element in the ul or outside the ul?

Tags: jquery

My task is to create a ul containing li-elements.

**I am unsure whether the li-elements are actually in the ul in my solution.**

If they are not, how do I create a ul and then insert the li-elements in the ul?

I am only allowed to change the JS-file.

All help would be greatly appreciated!

(I have included the html-code and the js-code down below.)

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Uppgift 4 – Dynamiskt visade och dolda sidkomponenter</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
     <div class="container">
     <div id="header" class="text-center px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="display-4">Husmanskost</h1>
        <p class="lead">Recept ur kokboken "Husmanskost – En hjälpreda för sparsamma 
    husmödrar" från 1896</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="row">
        <div id="primarycontainer" class="col">
            <div id="primarycontent" class="p-3">
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Potatis, att imkoka
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Bäst är att härtill hafva en särskild bleckkastrull, som är hålig i botten och passar att sätta öfver en kokande vattengryta.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Torra ärtskidor, att koka
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Som dessa ärtskidor äro hårdkokta, böra de komma tidigt på elden, den dag de skola ätas. De kokas och stufvas som föregående.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Släpärter
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            En bra stor gryta sättes på elden half med vatten, och då detta kokar, iläggas 4 lit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Spenat, stufvad
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Väl rensad och sköljd spenat förvälles i kokande vatten med salt, hvarefter den i durkslag bör afrinna och sedan hackas.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Kålrötter, brynta
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Rötterna skalas, skäras i klyftor och få koka som i föregående, men måste kallna innan de läggas i en stekpanna med fläskflott eller smör att brynas.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Rotslamp
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Kålrötter kokas som i föregående är sagdt, men inemot dä äro.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Kålrabbi
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Skala och skär sönder kålrabbi i strimlor, koka och stufva den som blomkål, men äggulorna kunna uteslutas.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    <h4>
                    Hvitkålshufvud, stekt
                </h4>
                    <div class="contentarea">
                        <p>
                            Ett stort hårdt kålhufvud afskäres alla gröna, skadade blad och med en smal, uddhvass knif bortskäres stocken. 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="secondarycontent" class="col-lg-4 p-3 bg-light">
            <div id="receptmeny">
                <h4>Recept</h4>
                <div class="contentarea">
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(generateMenu);

    function generateMenu() {
     //Loopar igenom alla headers
     $.each($('.post h4'),function(index,value){
     //Lägger in headertexten i rätt div tag och klass
     $('#receptmeny').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
     $('#receptmeny .contentarea').append('<li><a href="#anchor- 
     '+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></li>');
     //Lägger in headertag med motsvarande namn
     $(this).html('<a name="anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>');
      });
      }
```

Comment: You should be able to use the browser's inspect feature (not view-source as that's pre-javascript) - this will show you the HTML structure after you've built it.  However the browser may also "fix" your HTML for you eg it adds `tbody` when you don't have one, so may add `ul` around your `li` if you miss it.

Comment: You're appending `li` to `.contentarea` - so they are not within your `newList`

Comment: `$(this).html("..." + $(this).html() + "...")` - use .wrapInner https://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Comment: Thanks for the input! Bare with me, I am new to this: is the ul appended correctly to the div-tag?

Comment: I changed it to this:

$(document).ready(generateMenu);

function generateMenu() {

  $.each($('.post h4'),function(index,value){
 
 $('#receptmeny').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
  
$('#newList').append('<li><a href="#anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></li>');
 
$(this).html('<a name="anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>');
});
}

Comment: Yes, that looks good - but you only want to append `#newList` once - move that one line outside the loop/each otherwise you'll get multiple `ul`s with the same ID (it'll work as only the first one will have the `li`s attached, but it'll be messy)

Comment: This is the final code:
$(document).ready(generateMenu);

 $('#receptmeny .contentarea').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");

function generateMenu() {
 
 $.each($('.post h4'),function(index,value){

  $('#newList').append('<li><a href="#anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></li>');

  $(this).html('<a name="anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>');
});
}

Comment: More like: `$(document).ready(generateMenu); function generateMenu() { $('#receptmeny .contentarea').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>"); $.each($('.post h4'),function(index,value){ $('#newList').append('<li><a href="#anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a></li>'); $(this).html('<a name="anchor-'+index+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>'); }); }`

Comment: Doesn't that create multiple ul:s? My task is to create one ul and fill that ul with li-elements.

Comment: With the code in my last comment: when you call generateMenu - add one `ul` then add `li`s that that one ul.  If you call generateMenu twice then yes you'll get two `ul`s but also get all the `li`s duplicate, so guessing you'll only call it once.  So it's [add ul][loop-li] before you add [loop-ul-and-li].  You want it inside generateMenu otherwise there's not point having generateMenu